# Call generic method by reflection. System.ArgumentException happens

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I'm trying to call generic method via reflection. I need to pass object of class that implements interface this method expects for parameter. I'm getting System.ArgumentException telling me 'Object of type 'ReflectionTest.MyRequest' cannot be converted to type 'ReflectionTest.IRequest`1[ReflectionTest.MyRequest]'.'

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = new MyRequest();
        IMediator mediator = new Mediator();

        //This works (of course), but I need to call this by reflection. I don't know the type at design time.
        //var r = mediator.Send(request);

        //I tried this, but it doesn't work
        var type = request.GetType();
        var method = mediator.GetType().GetMethod("Send");
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        //Exception
        var response = generic.Invoke(mediator, new object[] { request });

    }
}

public interface IRequest<out TResponse>
{

}

public interface IMediator
{
    TResponse Send<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> requests);
}

public class MyRequest : IRequest<MyResponse>
{
}

public class MyResponse
{
}

public class Mediator : IMediator
{
    public TResponse Send<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> requests)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing...");
        return default(TResponse);
    }
}
```

Has anyone have some suggestion what I'm doing wrong? Unfortunately, I'm not that skilled with reflection so any help is welcome.

Sample git repo: https://github.com/alan994/ReflectionProblem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

You are creating a generic method of type `type`, which is `MyRequest`.
So, eventually you are using `MyRequest` as `TResponse`.

But what you actually want to do is you want to pass `MyResponse` as `TResponse`.

You can do the following in order to be able to call this dynamically:

- get the interface `IMyRequest<>` which is your request is implementing
- get the only generic argument of this interface, which will be `TResponse`

This is how the code might look like, but you need to add some checks on types and valid error handling here:

```
var type = request.GetType();

var responseType = type.GetInterfaces() // [IRequest<MyResponse>]
    .Single(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IRequest<>)) // IRequest<MyResponse>
    .GetGenericArguments() // [MyResponse]
    .Single(); // MyResponse

var method = mediator.GetType().GetMethod("Send");
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(responseType); // note that responseType is used here

var response = generic.Invoke(mediator, new object[] { request });
```

After all, are you sure that you want to bind your response to a specific definition of a request? I don't know your architecture and what you are trying to achieve, but, perhaps, this can be a more agile solution:

```
public interface IRequest
{

}

public interface IMediator
{
    TResponse Send<TRequest, TResponse>(IRequest request);
}

public class MyRequest : IRequest
{
}

public class MyResponse
{
}

public class Mediator : IMediator
{
    public TResponse Send<TRequest, TResponse>(IRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing...");
        return default(TResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation and code example. I see now and what can I say...I'm idiot :)

This is just small example of larger code base. Interface IMediator is part of external nuget package. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the wrong type for the generic type of the `Send` method.  Its generic type is the response type - `TResponse`, but you are giving it the request type - effectively `IRequest<TResponse>`.

The following will give you correct generic method to invoke.

```
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyReponse));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are making a generic method using `MyRequest` instead of `MyResponse`, take a look at the signature `Send<TResponse>`. Try:

```
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyReponse));
```